Tailwind does not draw gradient when color is thrown as props Next.js
Unexpectedly ran into this problem: I want to make squares in my application that will display colors in a particular site theme.
Problem: when I drop colors into the component, Tailwind for some reason refuses to draw a gradient.
Correction: even if the color is in a variable, it doesn't work either. My code:
"use client";

interface ISettingsThemePickerItemProps {
  startColor: string;
  endColor: string;
}

function SettingsThemePickerItem({
  startColor,
  endColor
}: ISettingsThemePickerItemProps) {
  const t = "#fff";
  return (
    <div
      className={
        `h-[100px] w-full rounded-2xl border bg-gradient-to-br from-[${t}] from-0% via-white via-50% to-red-500`
      }
    ></div>
  );
}

export default SettingsThemePickerItem;

When written like this, the gradient will not be displayed. In the browser you can see that the necessary classes are not being pulled. But if you go back to normal writing (from-[#fff]), everything will be fine

As per the documentation:

The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
Don’t construct class names dynamically
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>

In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
Always use complete class names
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>


You could:

Have the entire class in the t variable like
const t = "from-[#fff]";
return (
  <div
    className={
      `… ${t} …`
    }
  ></div>
);


Forego the t variable entirely like:
return (
  <div
    className="… from-[#fff] …"></div>
);




This answer seems to be true, but I see something strange: the classes worked when I put them in a separate variable (and yes, I can't put them in right away because I get them in props), but after stopping the server and then starting up again, the classes refuse to work again
Here's what I did:  const t = `from-[${startColor}] via-[${startColor}] to-[${endColor}]`;

The whole problem is that I want to do a gradient by getting the colors in a component. If I have to give up tailwind here, I don't know any solutions yet how to do a dynamic gradient properly

You'd want to use the style attribute – as per the documentation, Tailwind cannot compile CSS rules for truly dynamic classes.

It's kind of sad. But okay, thank you for all your help and time spent on me
